# How to performs Combination of rows with same values as a group?

Tags: mysql

i have a table with a structure somewhat like this:

```
date    name    marks
x       a       4
y       a       2
x       b       2
y       b       7
x       c       8
y       c       6
x       d       9
y       d       6
```

i'd like to perform combination of all the rows, however, same `name` should be taken as one while performing the combination. The output has to look like:

```
date    name    marks   x.date  x.name  x.marks
x       a       4       x       b       2   # a & b
y       a       2       y       b       7
x       a       4       x       c       8   # a & c
y       a       2       y       c       6
x       a       4       x       d       9   # a & d
y       a       2       y       d       6
x       b       2       x       d       9   # b & c
y       b       7       y       d       6
x       b       2       x       c       8   # b & d
y       b       7       y       c       6
x       c       8       x       d       9   # c & d
y       c       6       y       d       6
```

I have tired of various ides like cross join, group by, etc, but all in vain. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select a.date adate, a.name aname, a.marks amark, 
x.date xdate, x.name xname, x.marks xmarks
FROM A a, a x 
where A.name < x.Name and a.date = x.date
order by aname, xname, adate, xdate
```

Here's a fiddle with working demo.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/105f0/19/0

However in the future show your work.  Post queries you've tried so that people can point you in the right direction.

The trick here is two fold you want A.name that is < x.name but only when the a.date and x.dates match.  So a cross join is needed but you don't want to simply use a <> or =

Comment: lovely!! i was also trying your code http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b24959/1  Well, i was stuck on this prob for almost a month, finally u did it in just a few mins!! Wow! Thanks a million :)

Comment: yeah my order by wasn't complete on that fiddle, I corrected it to match your desired output on an updated one.  The trick is to think about the cartesean generated, and then what you can do to eliminate the rows you didn't want. once I saw there was no D name in your output for the first name in your output I knew I had to use a < that in a where clause and then I saw there were no X/y combinations I knew you had to limit on only those that matched on date!

Comment: ah! You are simply genius! Stackoverflow rocks 'cos of coders like you :)